# YA book with twins and a time machine

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

All I've got to go on is two of the protagonists who were twins and there was some sort of time machine in a shed? At the bottom of the garden? And an older relative was involved, maybe an Uncle?

I think I read this in the late 80s.

I know it's not much but does anyone know what this could be?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! Could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in any extra details you may remember? As it is your question is on the verge of being closed as too broad because of a lack of information.

Comment: I've also edited your question to be a bit clearer feel free to roll it back if you feel I've interpreted some of what you posted wrongly.

Comment: I would swear we've had this one before, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Were the twins boys, girls, or one of each? What did the (time) machine do/where or when did it send people?

Comment: Not a dup until/unless OP confirms that is the story they are looking for.

Comment: @amflare I think I only _flagged_ it as a duplicate ... maybe it automatically became a close vote? Anyway, vote retracted.

Comment: @lfurini - No worries, that's also a reminder for those who encounter the question in the review queues. BTW, since you are over the rep threshold, a flag converts to a vote for you.

Comment: Note that unaccepted answer below was provided by OP.

Answer (score 4):

I had a scan of the related questions and one of them refers to 'a book where a teen places a clock in a 'time portal' in his relatives' shed. The answer was 'Singularity' by William Sleator. I'm 99% sure this was it. It was a long time ago! I'm going to seek out a copy and read it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know that you have found your story. When possible can you accept your answer so that others can more easily tell this is correct.

Comment: I definitely will. Book is ordered and should arrive in the next couple of days. What is the protocol for accepting an answer? Do I just comment, or is there something I click on? Sorry for my ignorance ;-)

Comment: There is a tick next to the voting buttons on the left. Click that and it'll go green indicating that you've accepted it. There is a restriction of 2 days for self answers but I think you'll be fine here.

Answer (score 2):

A dark Traveling by Roger Zelazny also fits most of this.

- young adults novel
- sibling protagonists though not sure if twins
- uncle
- time machine - kind of. More of a trans dimension machine
- late 80’s - came out in 1987

Adding here just in case and for posterity

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Dark_Traveling

Comment: Thank you for the further information and suggestion. I had a look at the synopsis and I think whilst there are similarities it is probably not 'trashy/pulpy' enough. Sounds like good, sophisticated writing. Might give it a read sometime ;-)